# jQuery animate show stop hide combination

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a `div` class "saved" which is actually a notification div (see image link )

[image: Saved Div]

First it is positioned  `position: fixed; top: -50px;`

Whenever I change a checkbox or a input type color I want to show the "saved" div and after 1 second I want to hide the div which I achieve with the following code. Works pretty well.

```
$("input[type=checkbox], input[type=color]").on("change", function() { 
    $(".saved")
    .animate({ top: "10px" })
    .delay(1000)
    .animate({ top: "-50px" });     
});
```

However when I click a checkbox 10 times the div will be shown 10 times. I see the animation 10 times in a row. It goes down and up and down and up and down and up etc.

How can I achieve that it recognizes that it has to do it 10 times?

I tried a `.stop()` but that didn`t work.

Thanks!

Comment: can you try this https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work anymore :-(

Comment: plz check my new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE!!**

Sorry Aswin, somehow it worked but now it doesn't :-)

Please check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkctb7kx/)

---

**UPDATE 2!!**

This works!

See updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkctb7kx/2/)

```
$("input[type=checkbox], input[type=color]").on("change", function() { 
    $(".saved").clearQueue();
    $(".saved").stop();
    $(".saved")
    .animate({ top: "10px" })
    .delay(1000)
    .animate({ top: "-50px" });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

worked for me, check this https://jsfiddle.net/mkctb7kx/3/

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  $(".saved").animate({top: "10px"})
  $(".saved").delay(1000).animate({top: "-50px"}, function() {
    $(".saved").clearQueue();
  });  
});
```